# How to redirect traffic from one IP address to one page?

Tags: .htaccess

I am wondering, how can I redirect all traffic from certain IP address to one, specified page, so that the traffic is not able to access anything else?

So found, I've tried the following, but it didn't succeed - it doesn't change anything.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} = XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.com/404.html
```

I've tested this on my own ip address.

Comment: Most likely you did not enable the interpretation of `.htaccess` style files or placed that file in the wrong location. As a test, try coding a definite syntax error in that file. What happens? What do you see in your http servers error log file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out what the proper code should be:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.1\.1\.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/404.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* /404.html [R=302,L]
```

Which basically means:

1. First line: check if the address matches 1.1.1.1 (IP you want to redirect)
2. Second line: since we want to redirect them to `404.html`, we need to prevent infinity loop, by letting them access `404.html`
3. Third line: redirect them to `404.html`

Additionally, we can add:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
```

So that they will be able to access all the images, styles, and javascript files from the server.

Discussion whether to use `REMOTE_ADDR` or `REMOTE_HOST` is covered in many topics, and pretty much comes down to those two definitions:

> **REMOTE_ADDR** The IP address of the remote host that is making the
>   request.
>
> **REMOTE_HOST** The name of the host that is making the request.
>   If the server does not have this information, it will set REMOTE_ADDR
>   and leave this empty.